# adding string into the existing matrix in r

Tags: r, string

I want to add some strings after each element in the matrix or factor of the stock tickers.

```
require(stringr)
tickers <- as.factor(c(002707, 002712, 300397, 300213, 600304, 300245))
stocks <- c()
foo = function() for(i in 1 : length(tickers)){
  if(substr(tickers[i], 1, 1) < 6) {
    stocks[[i]] <- paste(str_pad(tickers[[i]],width=6,side="left",pad="0"),"SZ",sep=".")
  } else {
    stocks[[i]] <- paste(tickers[[i]],"SS",sep=".")
  }
  return(stocks)
}

foo()
```

What I got is just the

```
> foo()
[1] "002707.SZ"
```

not the full updated value for the stock tickers, what happen here?

Comment: it is not the point, all I want is just the correct string in the final matrix.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
  foo <- function(x){
    indx <- substr(x, 1, 1) < 6
    x <- as.numeric(as.character(x))
    sz <- sprintf('%06d.%s', x, 'SZ')
    ss <- paste0(x, '.SS')
   ifelse(indx, sz, ss)
  }


 foo(tickers)
 #[1] "002707.SZ" "002712.SZ" "300397.SZ" "300213.SZ" "600304.SS" "300245.SZ"
```

Comment: `ifelse` is the right solution here, although I'd suggest not doing everything in one line in the function body. as in, `{ sz <- sprintf('%06d.%s', as.numeric(as.character(x)), 'SZ'); ss <- paste(x, 'SS', sep='.'); ifelse(substr(x,1,1) < 6, sz, ss); }`

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler to use sapply:

```
foo2 <- function(t) {
  if(substr(t,1,1) < 6) {
    return(paste(str_pad(t,width=6,side="left",pad="0"),"SZ",sep="."))
  } else {
    return(paste(t,"SS",sep="."))
  }
}

stocks <- sapply(tickers,foo2)

.# [1] "002707.SZ" "002712.SZ" "300397.SZ" "300213.SZ" "600304.SS" "300245.SZ"
```

Comment: ,Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : unused argument (X[[1]]). it doesn't work.

Comment: Your foo was a mess so I cleaned it up. Again, use sapply. Don't start indexing into args.